# Print the number that appears the maximum number of times in the sequence

Tags: c, performance

Recently I have gone through a problem like this

Write a program to read a sequence of N integers and print the number that 
appears the maximum number of times in the sequence. 
CONSTRAINTS
1 <= N <= 10000
The integers will be in the range [-100,100]

I have writen the following code:

```
main()
{int arr[201],max=0,maxelement,n,i,num;
int t;
scanf("%d",&n);
int *storenum=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
 for(i=0;i<201;i++)
 {
             arr[i]=0;
 }
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
             scanf("%d",&num);
             storenum[i]=num;
             if(num<=100 && num>=-100)
             {
                         arr[num+100]=arr[num+100]+1;

             }
 }
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
             int t=storenum[i]+100;


         if(arr[t]>max)
        { maxelement=storenum[i];
         max=arr[t];}

 }

    printf("\n\n%d",maxelement);     

getch();
}
```

Now I think this code is not optimized one...I want to have a solution that would have less time and space complexity and better solution.

Comment: Is there a question here? Also, this should belong on Code Review

Comment: Don't forget to profile, before and after.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to iterate through all N items a second time, just iterate through the 201 counts looking for the largest.

Comment: +1 this is not only correct, it is near-optimal There could be 10,000 numbers, and testing each, `if (x!=most && freq[x] > freq[most]) most=x;`, (first expr to eliminate the two dereferences on repeated numbers) up to 10,000 times will be considerably more expensive than a single pass over a fixed 201-slot array after the counting loop, essentially performing an initial selection sort pass without exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks very close to optimal. It can be made only a little better given your constraints.

1. Use memset when you mean memset. Yes the compiler will pick it up 99% of the time, but why bother?

   ```
   for(i=0;i<201;i++) arr[i]=0; // becomes
   memset(arr, '\0', sizeof(arr))
   ```
2. The count for any given item can be no larger than 10000. That means it can be held in a ushort!

   ```
   int arr[201]; // becomes
   uint16_t arr[201];
   ```
3. Your second loop should go from `for(i = -100; i <= 100; i++)` instead, and just loop over `arr`.
4. Your code is butt-ugly. Use a consistent indentation, brace style, and don't cram 50 declarations on the same line. Spaces are okay between elements. `arr` should probably be named something meaningful, I like `counts`. It kind of looks like you're trying to use gnu style C, but K&R works too, really just pick any style guide and glance through it.

Comment: why use memset at all: `int arr[201]={0};`

Comment: @AShelly Get off my lawn! But yes, that version is much better if it's available. Frankly I'm not sure what version of C the author is using.

Comment: I believe that has worked since the days of K&R. p219: "If there are fewer initializers in the list than members of the structure, the trailing members are initialized with 0."